# QGraphicsRotation to QRectF?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qrect

I want to rotate QRectF in PyQT4 by given angle around bottom left corner. I know how to draw a rectangle but I'm stuck on how to rotate it. I tried with rotate(), but it rotates the coordinate system the given angle clockwise.

Is there any easy solution (except drawing a Polygon by changing coordinates)?

```
margin = 10
width = 100
depth = 20
self.p = QPainter(self)
self.rectangle = QRectF(margin, margin, width, depth)
self.angle = 30
self.p.rotate(self.angle)
self.p.drawRect(self.rectangle)
self.p.end()
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. But I don't think it will help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

you can move the rotation center (always top left corner) to an arbitrary point of the widget by `painter.translate()`, paint the rectangle with top left corner in the rotation center,  calculate the x- and y- offset of your wanted rotation center and move the object again, then rotate the coordinate system for the next object. here a working example in pyqt5, replace QtWidgets by QtGui for pyqt4:

```
import sys 
import math
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MeinWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setGeometry(200,50,300,300)
        self.pen1 = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))
        self.pen2 = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255,0,0))
        self.pen3 = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,255,0))
        self.pen4 = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,255))
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))

        self.pens = (self.pen1, self.pen2, self.pen3, self.pen4)
        self.rw = 100
        self.rh = 50

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.translate(QtCore.QPointF(self.rw,self.rh))      # move rotation center to an arbitrary point of widget
        angle = 10
        for i in range(0,len(self.pens)):
            dy = self.rh - self.rh*math.cos(math.radians(angle))    # vertical offset of bottom left corner
            dx = self.rh*math.sin(math.radians(angle))          # horizontal offset of bottom left corner
            p = self.pens[i]
            p.setWidth(3)
            painter.setPen(p)
            painter.drawRect(0,0,self.rw,self.rh)
            painter.translate(QtCore.QPointF(dx,dy))            # move the wanted rotation center to old position 
            painter.rotate(angle)
            angle += 10

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)      
widget = MeinWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

looks like this:

[image: rotation of a rectangle around bottom left]